# How to correctly optimize JDBC code if the preparedStatements can change depending on the object?

Tags: java, postgresql

so I have a small problem.

In my Java code I have multiple PreparedStatements, which, according to my professor, should be implemented in the constructor of the class. For that I basically did something like :

```
 private PreparedStatement getWardStatement, getHospitalStayStatement, deletePatientFromHospitalStayStatement, selectPatientFromPatientStatement, selectWardStatement, averageBedNumberStatement;
private static final String SELECT_FROM_WARD = "SELECT * FROM Ward";
private static final String DELETE_FROM_HOSPITAL_STAY_HO_S_WHERE_HO_S_HO_ID = "DELETE FROM HospitalStay hoS WHERE hoS.HoID= ?";
private static final String SELECT_FROM_PATIENT_P_WHERE_P_PA_ID = "SELECT * FROM Patient p WHERE p.PaID = ?";
private static final String SELECT_FROM_WARD_WHERE_WA_ID = "SELECT * FROM Ward  WHERE waID = ?";
private static final String SELECT_WARD_HOS_P_WITH_PAID = "SELECT * FROM HospitalStay hoS, Patient p , Ward w WHERE hoS.patientid = p.PaID AND hos.wardid = w.waid AND hos.patientid = ?";
private static final String AVERAGE_SQL = "SELECT avg(CAST((hoS.discharge - hoS.admission)AS DOUBLE PRECISION)) AS average FROM HospitalStay hoS WHERE hoS.wardid = ? AND hoS.discharge IS NOT NULL";
private static final String FREEBED_SQL = "SELECT (sum(w.numberofbeds) - (SELECT count(*) FROM HospitalStay WHERE discharge IS NULL)) AS freeBeds FROM Ward w";
private Connection conPSQL;

public BasicDBImpl() {
    getConnection();
    try {
        getWardStatement = conPSQL.prepareStatement(SELECT_FROM_WARD_WHERE_WA_ID);
        deletePatientFromHospitalStayStatement = conPSQL.prepareStatement(DELETE_FROM_HOSPITAL_STAY_HO_S_WHERE_HO_S_HO_ID);
        selectPatientFromPatientStatement = conPSQL.prepareStatement(SELECT_FROM_PATIENT_P_WHERE_P_PA_ID);
        selectWardStatement = conPSQL.prepareStatement(SELECT_FROM_WARD);
        getHospitalStayStatement = conPSQL.prepareStatement(SELECT_WARD_HOS_P_WITH_PAID);
        averageBedNumberStatement = conPSQL.prepareStatement(AVERAGE_SQL);

    } catch (SQLException e) {
        throw new FetchException(e);
    }
}
```

My first question basically would be if I can use the try/catch in this context in the constructor. The reason for my worries is that if one statement isn't going through, the others wouldn't too...

My second question would be how to do the same concept of putting all the preparedStatements in the constructor if the Statement can be changed, depending on if a certain object or so is null or not.

Example :

```
   public int getNotFreeBeds(Ward ward) {

    assert ward == null || ward.isPersistent() : "Ward is not persistent";

    String countSql = "SELECT COUNT(*) AS count FROM HospitalStay hoS WHERE hoS.Discharge IS NULL";

    if (ward != null) {
        countSql += " AND hoS.WardID = ?";
    }

    try (PreparedStatement preparedStatement = conPSQL.prepareStatement(countSql)) {

        if (ward != null) {
            preparedStatement.setLong(1, ward.getObjectID());
        }

        ResultSet set = preparedStatement.executeQuery();
        set.next();
        return set.getInt("count");

    } catch (SQLException e) {
        throw new FetchException(e);
    }

}
```

The professor said we should do a method where we create all possible PreparedStatements using an if cascade, but I have no clue how to do it in the constructor, because of the objects.

Comment: I disagree with your professor. Connections should not be class members, they should be metod-local, and that alone makes caching `PreparedStatements` in the class instance impossible. Just create whatever `PreparedStatement` you need, *when you need it,*, and let the database server worry about caching them, which it already does.

Comment: I disagree too, but I have no choice sadly  :( . Because if we don't do it, I will just fail lol

Comment: Well I don't see how this can be done in the constructor if it depends on objects supplied to methods called later on. I think you need to post the actual text of the assignment. But if your concern is only about the `try/catch`, all you have to do is make sure there are no SQL syntax errors and there won't be any exceptions. In fact you should rarely have a `try-catch` blocks in constructors at all: just let the constructor throw the exception to the caller. The object isn't much use if only half-constructed.

Comment: Don't vandalize your own posts. If you want to conceal your question, delete it.

Answer (score 1):

> which, according to my professor, should be implemented in the constructor of the class.

That's unfortunate.

It means your professor has no idea what they are talking about.

> `getConnection();`

methods named `getX` should, as a rule, be side effect free. Clearly here it isn't side effect free (invoking SEF methods and ignoring what they return is a no-operation).

> `private Connection conPSQL;`

Having a Connection be a field like this is tricky; connections are **resources** - they are objects that hold a 'handle' to a system resource; a resource where you can only have a few (in the case of DB connections, most DBs are configured to allow anywhere from 20 to 100 or so of them). The problem is, as long as that Connection object exists, you're holding 1 of those precious 100 slots 'hostage', and you have no idea when an object in java is garbage collected. It may literally take **a week** - the JVM is not going to aggressively collect all garbage as soon as it can, it's just not how it works (and would be highly inefficient on most setups).

This is why resources **MUST ALWAYS** be protected. You protect them using the following ruleset:

1. You always open them using a `try (Connection con = openConnection()) { code goes here }` construct: This gives you access to `con` within the block, and guarantees that `con` is closed no matter how code exits this block. You can return from it, you can let it run to its end, you can `break;` out of it, or you can throw an exception out of it, does not matter. -OR-
2. Alternatively, any object that has a resource field must them itself *become* a resource object: add `implements AutoClosable`, add a `close()` method that closes these resources, and now any code that uses *your class* will need to write `try (YourThing thing = new YourThing()) { ... }` to use it.

Any other option is such bad style, it's bordering on an outright bug.

Clearly none of this is happening.

> I disagree too, but I have no choice sadly :( . Because if we don't do it, I will just fail lol

So you're asking Stack Overflow to find a crystal ball, look into it, and attempt to fathom what the preferred code style is of a professor that doesn't know the basics?

Sadly we're all out of crystal balls.

The above approach (making your own object itself AutoClosable) also gives you a route to closing those preparedstatements. Also, if you close a connection, generally everything derived from it (such as PreparedStatements) is, itself, closed.

Thus, faced with the **bonkers** idea of doing it this way, the only sensible strategy is precisely that.

However, I  bet your prof isn't looking for that. But what they are looking for? Good question.

Presumably you're taking this course because you want a career in programming / want to write a cool app / want to learn something, and not because your parents disown you or you get shot if you fail. You may want to focus more on the learning part and less on the 'what does crazy prof want' part.

Comment: Well said. Another ***major*** issue with having the `Connection` as an instance member is that the class isn't thread-safe.

Comment: I disagree on always having a connection in a try block.  Generally it is a good idea, but there are valid use cases to persist the connection. For example, you may want to keep a connection open because you have an open COMMIT block in the database.

Comment: @JimD Neverthess it should be a method-local variable somewhere, and passed around as a method parameter. Not a class member. Otherwise the class cannot be thread-safe.

Comment: @user207421 Agreed--best that each thread has its own connection or one thread acts as a broker for other thread (e.g. scatter/gather).

Comment: @JimD I explained in the answer what it takes if you want to keep a resource object around in a field: Then _YOUR_ object must be autoclosable. If you do that, you can keep an open connection around. If you don't do that, then you've lost the plot and there is no valid use case left. At least, I don't think it's a good idea to characterize leaving a resource leak alive is 'a valid use case'. I guess in one-and-day tossaway code, but you can use that argument to justify a break for every rule we have.

Comment: @rzwitserloot I think we are saying the same thing. Sometimes you need to persist a JDBC Connection beyond a try block. Wrapping it in a class that manages the connection (e.g. not closing the connection until a specific state is reached) is the usual solution. My wrap class implements AutoCloseable and takes the appropriate action.  Another use case is opening a JDBC connection using an LDAP based authentication mechanism. Because it can be expensive time-wise, keeping a connection open can be necessary in some cases. Apache DBCP, for example, shares a pool of open JDBC connections.

Comment: @JimD To which the solution is to use a connection pool. Not a class member.

Comment: Agreed. A class member is not the way to go